# Lines on Hilbert Schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hartshorne proved that Hilbert Schemes of projective space are linearly connected. I was wondering, are there/should there be known examples (or suspected ones), where some irreducible components of a Hilbert Scheme of $\mathbb{P}^n$ (of dimension $\geq 1$) are/are not rationally connected?

Comment: For every integer $g\geq 1$, for every integer $d\geq 2g-1$, for $r=d-g$, the unique irreducible component of  $\text{Hilb}^{dt+1-g}_{\mathbb{P}^r}$ parameterizing smooth, connected curves admits a dominant morphism to $\mathcal{M}_g$ by Riemann-Roch.  Thus, by the Harris-Mumford-Eisenbud theorem, for $g\geq 24$, this irreducible component is not rationally connected.  On the other hand, there are many irreducible components that are rationally connected, e.g., $\text{Hilb}^n_{\mathbb{P}^2}$.